# Why is the paste event firing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js, paste

The paste event fires twice for me in Chrome v45 on Ubuntu. However, if I Switch to Firefox it fires only once, as it should. Is this a bug in my code or a bug in the Chrome browser?

I have a minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/054e94p1/

In case the fiddle doesn't work the code is:

```
<div id="a" contenteditable="true">
  CONTENT
</div>

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {'paste' : 'pasteHandler'},
  pasteHandler: function(event){alert('yes');}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    new MyView({el : '#a'});
});
```

It depends on JQuery, underscore, and backbone.

UPDATE: After reading the comments, I realized that if I remove the alert and replace it with a console.log, the event only fires once. It seems that the alert message is somehow part of the problem.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't use `alert()` for debugging purpose even i don't see how this could be an issue here with `paste` event

Comment: only fires once for me in windows chrome

Comment: Issue isn't unheard of: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=299805 (But unconfirmed)

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome v45 Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: To add to @A.Wolff please use console.log("...") for your debugging purposes, save yourself some pain

Comment: I'm having this issue with `window.prompt` so the issue does exist (but alerts and prompts suck anyway so good riddance...)